# Install Firefox on lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, firefox

I have already download Firefox for Lubuntu a (Firefox.tar.bz2 file) and I have extracted the file after downloading. I have lot of files in that folder. from there, which file do I need to select for installation? can you please help me with the installation steps

I have no idea about Linux please help in detail

Comment: As a new user of Linux you may be better off to install stable software from the Ubuntu repositories rather than by downloading source code until you had learned enough to install (and remove) applications from other sources.

Answer (score 1):

### How you compile a program from a source

1. open a console
2. use the command `cd` to navigate to the correct folder. If there is a README file with installation instructions, use that instead.
3. extract the files with one of the commands

   - If it's **tar.gz** use `tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz`
   - if it's a **tar.bz2** use `tar xvjf PACKAGENAME.tar.bz2`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `sudo make install`

This is taken from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file/80593#80593) source.

Comment: I need to learn how to install a software which was downloaded already

Comment: can you please explain what dose these things means          

4.
./configure

5.make
6.sudo make install